# Dojo codependent filteringselects in dgrid

Tags: select, dojo, dgrid

I would like to implement a codependent filteringselect layout in a dojo dgrid.
I tried to follow this tutorial:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect#codependent-filteringselect-combobox-widgets

My problem is, that I can not access the value of the first filteringselect to set the second one in the dgrid like in the example, because the selects don't have an id.

How can I cross-reference the values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try inspecting the element with Firebug (right click->inspect element)? You can see the id that Dojo assigns to elements that way.